# how to find the most frequent number in 1T numbers?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, find

How to find the most frequent number(int type) in 1T (i.e. 10^12) numbers?

My premises are:

- My memory is limited to 4G (i.e. 4·10^9) bytes.
- All the numbers are stored in a file as the input.
- The output is just one number.
- All numbers(int type) are stored in one or serval files
- The file structure is eithor binary or line-stored.

---

Edited at : 2013.04.22 17:08
Thanks for you comments:
Plus:
 - External Storage is not limited.

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Comment: How big are the numbers?

Comment: Does the number occur more than half the time?

Comment: You can try to use histograms.

Comment: Start by buying a supercomputer.. :D

Comment: Merge sort using an external storage

Comment: do you know that there is one number more frequent than all the others?

Comment: @Thilo There is always some "most frequent number", although there may be a tie between "N" of them in that position.

Comment: Can you use external storage?

Comment: @DanielDaranas: which is a problem if "N" is big, worst case is 1T (i.e. all numbers are distinct)

Comment: Can anyone kindly explain what Mr Wung wants to ask.Going by your comments and answers, it seems pretty heavy sophisticated stuff,but Mr.Wung's question is too concise for me.Thanks.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes. In any case the problem _is_ a problem, because there are many numbers and you will only know which is the most frequent one (and the tie, if any) at the end. It is a costly calculation.

Comment: Can someone   edit the question and make it simpler for the average folks like me?I really want to understand & appreciae what's being discussed here.

Comment: @SheerFish The issue is you have 1T (2^40) numbers, and only 4GB (2^32) space. You want to find the most frequent number out of those 2^40 numbers

Comment: Just to be picky, what does "1T numbers" mean, really? Is it one terabyte of numeric data? In what format? Or is it 10 to the 12:th items? Again, in what format are the numbers themselves?

Comment: I edited it, although I am not the author. If the author meant something different, he may edit it again.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: "In any case the problem is a problem". Which is why it would be nice to know that there are no ties (or even a super-frequent number like rmmh suggested) in advance (as part of the problem specification). Or that the number are already sorted. Or that they are int32. Or if external storage is available. These "details" make all the difference here.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but I think the "hard" problem is in the general case. i.e. Give an answer which will work for any given input. If "today"'s file is easy (one number occurs 90% of times), good luck.  "Tomorrow"'s file may have totally different data. This is not necessarily the real case, but it's the only one for which answers are interesting, I think.

Comment: Re: "hard general problem". People do seem to assume in their answers that external storage is available. The question does not say that.

Comment: @amit 1 gigabyte is 10^9 bytes, so 4 gigabytes are 4·10^9 bytes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte.

Comment: @StevenWung: You need to tell us if external storage is available, and how big the numbers are. Otherwise it is underspecified and I'll vote to close.

Comment: @Thilo, Thanks for your comment, I assume the exteral storage space is infinitely big.

Comment: If you say "The output is just one number" you must specify what happens for the following sequence: 37, 500, 2, 500, 8, 37, 9, 9; in which three numbers (9, 37 and 500) tie as the "most frequent".

Comment: @StevenWung What are the sizes of your numbers? 2^16, 2^32, 2^64 or anything custom?

Answer (score 3):

First note that the problem is at least as hard as the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

Thus, the solutions should follow the same approaches:

1. sort (using [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)) and iterate while counting occurances for each number and looking for the maximal.
2. Hashing solution: hash the numbers into buckets that fit in memory (note that all occurances of the same number will be hashed to the same bucket), for each bucket - find the most frequent number, and store it. Then go through all candidates from all buckets and chose the best.

   In here, you can either sort (in memory) each bucket and find the most frequent number or you can create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (using a hash map, with a different hash function) to find the frequency of each item in the bucket.

   Note that the buckets are written on disk, and loaded into memory one after the other, at each time only a small part of the data is stored on RAM.

Another more scalable approach could be using [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), with a simple map-reduce step to count number of occurances per number, and then just find maximum of those:

```
map(number):
  emit(number,'1')
reduce(number,list):
  emit (number, size(list))
```

all is left is to find the number with the highest value - which can be done in linear scan.

Comment: For 2, how do you find the most frequent number for each bucket?

Comment: @Thilo It is in memory, you can either sort (in memory, and follow the idea of 1) or to create histogram of the elements per bucket

Comment: How can you guarantee that any bucket fits into memory?

Comment: @Thilo Simple, hash the numbers into buckets using `hash1(number)`. It fits? good. It's not? hash them again using `hash2(number)`. Repeat until all buckets fit in memory.

Comment: @amit Can you explain the question for me please?I feel I am missing out important stuff.

Comment: @SheerFish this belongs on comments on the question itself, ask there what exactly are you not understanding and I'll try to help.

Comment: @amit What does he mean by "How to find the most frequent number in 1T numbers?" Does he mean the total number of numbers, or he means the storage?

Comment: Why would they somehow magically fit into memory? If the first 100G numbers are all distinct, you need to store 100G entries in memory, no?

Comment: @Thilo You store them in buckets on disk, each bucket contain numbers with certain hash value, after it is done, you load buckets into memory one after the other, each bucket does fit into memory, but the entire data is written only on disk at the same time. This is common trick to implement things like *union* in data base systems with large data. i.e. the RAM stores only a small part of the data at each time.

Comment: okay, you did not mention external storage until now for the hash solution.

Comment: What if all of the elements (or enough to fill memory) are the same? Then, no matter how you hash it, that single bucket will never fit into memory.

Comment: @Thilo thought that was trivial, I'll calrify in the answer itself.

Comment: @Xymostech This edge case is simple to escape if you see after `k` hashes you get the same size of a bucket - and all you need then is a linear scan to verify it is indeed the case, and just add (number,repeats) as the most occuring number of this bucket.

Comment: This method can give wrong result in some cases: for example, our number can have low frequency in each bucket, but summary it will be a *mode* of that numbers. I mean, anyway you will need to merge all baskets into one big sorted array. Using histogram meets the same problem.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Read the answer carefuly. All same numbers (including most frequent number) **will be in the same bucket**, because we create these buckets according to their *hash value*, which is identical across the data. So, our number cannot have low frequency in all buckets - it has frequency 0 in all buckets but one, and the number of repeats there is the number of repeats across the entire data.

Comment: @amit, in this case you will need to scan all data many and many times (at least equal to number of buckets + 1).

Comment: @Eddy_Em No, you can scan the data once, and create buckets on disk. (`n` reads + `n` writes), then you will need to scan each bucket and insert it into RAM (`n` extra reads). This is a common implementation of [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union) in data base systems.

Comment: @amit, I agree: you can divide all data into portions and find a hystogram on every portion. But after that you need to merge them. If frequency of every number will be small, you will need a lot of memory for merging, or merge "buckets" by pairs. And only after getting last huge histogram you will be able certainly tell what is the mode of number sequence.

Answer (score 1):

What's about using filesystem to store counters of numbers?

For example, if your numbers are uint32, you can create 65536 directories with 65536 files in each. 
Name of directory will be two high bytes of a number, name of file - low two bytes. When you meet number X, you split it into two parts and get filename, open that file and increment counter inside it (or write there 1, if file is absent).

After filling that file structure you can scan recursively your tree finding file with greatest value.

That would be very slowly, but will almost eat none RAM.

Comment: While I like your proposal to abuse the file system I have to point out that you only allow for counting `2^32<10^10` numbers; and only those numbers in the range `0..(2^32)-1`.  As it stands I fear that this proposal fails to meet the requirements of the question.  Throw in another level of directory nesting ...

Comment: No, there's may be any amount of numbers: you just need to select proper type of counter. As for range of numbers, I've mention this in my answer. Anyway, if range of numbers is limited by not very big number, this case will work perfectly.

Comment: Why not put more than 1 number in each file? Not that I think having anywhere close to 2^32 files is a good idea. And I'd definitely suggest keeping track of the max as you go rather than scanning through all the files at the end.

Comment: @Dukeling, indeed, in that case there would be less files. But operation would be more slowly (because you will need to re-read each file to found corresponding counter). As for tracking mode in realtime, I absolutely agree with you: it would heavily reduce searching time. If files would be store on a SSD, all procedure will be quick enough.

Comment: Also, you could read numbers into an in-memory map of number to count and only push to file once you get close to 4G (you'll obviously need to add to the data in the files, which is probably preferred to reading the data from the files once you encounter a value). Many numbers per file will make this more efficient.

Comment: @Dukeling, no. In that case we will have similar numbers in different files (or we'll need to scan input file many times). I've mention that upper in comments to amit's answer. If we'll try to build a histograms of data by pieces, the merging of histograms into one would be a very slow operation.

Comment: I mean: Your files will have exactly the same data, when you write is just different. Rather than only 1 increment at a time, wait until you fill up memory and hopefully have a few more increments and only write this value to the appropriate file then.

Comment: Understand. Yes, maybe this method would noticeably increase productivity.

Comment: maybe, you can (mis-)use the filename instead the content of the file. you can name the file "count.number" and rename it later to "count+1.number". At the end: order numeric and you get your maximum

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash-table the key is the number, the value is the count. O(n) to insert all the numbers in the hashtable O(Unique numbers) to find the most frequent.

Comment: He will run out of memory _for sure_, for what he says in his question (4G memory, 1T numbers).

Comment: Not for sure, those are not 1T distinct numbers. But probably.

Comment: Also, not knowing how big these numbers are, each of those could have 4G digits.

Comment: You may want to say "assuming the number range is (<=) ..., which would lead to (<=) (... times ...) bytes total memory used for the hash table, which is <= 4G." or similar.

Answer (score 0):

brute force:

- remember = 0;
- repeat:

  - take the first unmarked number and count its occurance in the file (n1).
  - mark each occurance of number as read. (overwrite it with blanks f.e)
  - if (n1 > remember) remember = n1;

Comment: Brute force ... indeed. Let's say 10^9 distinct numbers (i.e. average 1000 occurrences each), which is basically a 4-byte int - Bytes read = `10^9 * 10^12 * 4` = `10^21 * 4`, at 100 MB/sec read speed (pretty fast for a hard drive), it'll take just over 441515887 years (assuming my analysis is correct).